# How can you call a static method in Symfony's YAML config?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an application that uses Symfony components.
Everything went great until I hit a wall when I was needed to add Symfony's request object to dependency injection container.

Here's my config:

```
parameters:
  config.project: %project_cfg%
  config.module: %module_cfg%
  config.mysql: %mysql_cfg%
  config.couch: %couch_cfg%
  request: %http_request%

services:
  request:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
    calls:
      - [createFromGlobals]
  db:
    class: App\Core\AlarisDb
    arguments: ["%mysql_cfg%"]
  func:
    class: App\Core\AlarisFunctions
    calls:
      - [setTree, ["@tree"]]
  tree:
    class: App\Core\AlarisTree
```

Everything works perfect, except that request is not created properly, because in PHP it should be called like this:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

Whereas YAML config calls it as object's method. Is there a way to tell it to call it as a static method?

Comment: Don't instanciate a second request instance! Neither pass the request object as a service argument *(your service would be in request scope)*. If you need the request object, make your service subscribe to [**onKernelRequest**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) event

Comment: Who's to say that he is running the `HttpKernel` component?

Comment: @Qoop That's true, I've read the question way too quickly and immediately assumed he was running the whole framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think this needs a factory call rather than a "calls" call, like..

```
request:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
    factory_class:  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
    factory_method: createFromGlobals
```

For more on factories see [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html).

Comment: Yes, this is how you can create services via static methods. However, you should mention that this is wrong to do it for the request.

Comment: I would have if I knew it was wrong. Feel free to stick some info about it in a comment and I will update my "answer".

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong to create a request object.  And yes, using a factory is the way to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `"Synthetic Services"` is what you are looking for:

> Synthetic services are services that are injected into the container
>   instead of being created by the container.

More: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#synthetic-services